# SQL Server database error: Cannot assign a new page to the database because the group files does not have sufficient space

Tags: sql-server

I have set up a database in SQL and I am running a program which downloads and populates the database. This was working for me when I first set up the database but it now does not work. The error I get is the following:

> Could not allocate a new page for database 'FDSLoaderDB' because of
> insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'. Create the necessary
> space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to
> the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the
> filegroup.

I have looked online on how to resolve this issue but non of the suggested solutions work. I have tried to update the file sizes in the figure below.

[image]

I did this by running the following code:

```
USE FDSLoaderDB
Go
SELECT growth*8 as filegrowth_KB FROM sys.database_files Where name = N'FDSLoaderDB_log'
Go

USE master
Go
ALTER DATABASE FDSLoaderDB MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'FDSLoaderDB_log', FILEGROWTH = 5GB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED) -- adjust size here
Go

USE FDSLoaderDB
Go
SELECT growth*8 as filegrowth_KB FROM sys.database_files Where name = N'FDSLoaderDB_log'
Go



USE FDSLoaderDB
Go
SELECT growth*8 as filegrowth_KB FROM sys.database_files Where name = N'FDSLoaderDB'
Go

USE master
Go
ALTER DATABASE FDSLoaderDB MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'FDSLoaderDB', FILEGROWTH = 5GB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED) -- adjust size here
Go

USE FDSLoaderDB
Go
SELECT growth*8 as filegrowth_KB FROM sys.database_files Where name = N'FDSLoaderDB'
Go




USE master;
Go
ALTER DATABASE tempdb
MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'tempdev', SIZE = 60GB, FILEGROWTH = 5GB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)

USE master;
Go
ALTER DATABASE tempdb
MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'templog', SIZE = 20GB, FILEGROWTH = 5GB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED);
Go
```

I re-run the program to re-populate the data and I get the same errors.

The log file of the program populating the database is in the following [link](https://ln4.sync.com/dl/6740231d0/jbrwy97q-trumqg3w-yzppvyrg-iqvetn93).

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My congratulations.
Seems your database is bigger than 10GB and you use SQL Server express Edition which has limit 10 GB per database
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks for this information! Any suggestion to a work-around for this? I had this working previously without errors, could it be that, since I have tried to run this program downloader many times it not replacing the data just appending the data to the database...

Comment: Yes, quite possible. I guess, you can try create another database and try to insert your data there

Comment: Thanks, I did try to create another database by right clicking on `databases` and selecting `new database` - I re-ran the program but had the same errors.

Comment: Are you sure, that your software writes data to the new database?

Comment: I will be honest, I am not 100% sure what I am doing. The program downloads the data and does populate the new database with the data but it contains some strange names. These strange names are only supposed to be temporary. i.e. `fds_scratch.dcs_v2_dcs_89c3dbf92ccc1d` should be called something like `dcs_v2.dcs_myCleanTable`. So the new database gets populated as the old database but because the program cannot complete the download/processing I have this problem. (I added an edit to the original post to show the tables in the DB)

Comment: In any case you always have another option. Use SQL Server Developer Edition. It does not have any limits on DB-size and you will be available to download and write everything you want

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look into this!